# PHP : How to select another column

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 columns in my table username, password and element. The value of element is 1. So I created a webpage If user insert the correct username and password I want my PHP to check that If element = 1 then do something I want and change element to 0. But If it is 0 so PHP do nothing. My problem is it's display white screen.

```
<?php
  require_once("function/func_connect.php");
  require_once("function/func_check.php");
  require_once("function/websend.php");
$objLogin = checkPassword($_POST['user_name'],$_POST['user_password'],$Cfg["table"]["user"]);
if($objLogin == false)
{
        include("state/login_failed.html");
        exit();
}
if($objLogin == true)
{
// I think the problem cause here How do I fix?
    mysql_query("SELECT element FROM authme WHERE username = $_POST['user_name']");
    echo "success";
}
    mysql_close();
?>
```

Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please stop using the `mysql_*` functions. They are considered to be deprecated and unsecure. You should look into using [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: You should also turn on `Display Errors` in PHP while developing and there wouldn't have been a need for the question. It would have showed you the syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic error is you are not wrapping your string value in quotes.

```
mysql_query("SELECT element FROM authme WHERE username = $_POST['user_name']");
```

should be

```
mysql_query("SELECT element FROM authme WHERE username = '$_POST['user_name']'");
```

But, just as important, you are wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174). You need to fix that ASAP.

You also need to turn on [error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) so you can see your errors instead of getting just a white screen.

FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).